# Computing derivatives?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

Let $u: \Bbb R^2\to\Bbb R$ and define $f(t)=u(\sin(t),\cos(t))$

How may I calculate $f'(t)$?

**Note: I am expecting the answer to include symbols like ${\partial u}/ {\partial x}$**

Is there a law for such kind of derivatives?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule

Comment: if u(x,y) what is g in my case, in other words what functions I'm composing here?

Comment: $g(t)=(\sin(t),\cos(t))$

Comment: The given link doesn't suit your case at all since you have 2 variables, I don't know why it was suggested at all

Comment: may someone help with explanation for general use?

Comment: Why insisting in clumsy partial derivatives?  Isn't $$\langle\nabla u(f(t)),f'(t)\rangle$$ much more pleasant (besides it's much more elegant)?

Comment: @MichaelHoppe In $\mathbb{R}^n$ equipped with the usual inner product there is no difference between $Du(g(t)) \cdot g''(t)$ and $\langle \nabla u (g(t)) , g'(t)\rangle$. But thinking of things this way is eventually more trouble than it's worth. Once you deal with curvilinear coordinates or Riemannian manifolds it becomes important to distinguish these objects, and I think it's better to get in the habit of distinguishing them sooner than later.

Comment: Should be $Du(g(t)) \cdot g'(t)$. My mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you're not sure about how to compute a derivative, the best approach is to break it down into a composition of functions and apply the chain rule.

Define $g(t) = (\sin t, \cos t)$. Then $f(t) = u(g(t))$, i.e. $f = u \circ g$. Thus
$$
Df(t) = Du (g(t)) \cdot Dg(t) = \begin{bmatrix}\partial_x u & \partial_y u \end{bmatrix} \cdot \begin{bmatrix}\cos t \\ -\sin t \end{bmatrix} = \cos (t) \, \partial_x u (g(t)) - \sin(t)\, \partial_y u (g(t))
$$
So
$$
f'(t) = \cos(t) \, \partial_x u(\sin t, \cos t) - \sin(t)\, \partial_y u(\sin t, \cos t)
$$

Comment: may you take a look at my comments?

Comment: I defined $g$ in my answer. $\partial_x u$ is a standard shorthand for the unwieldy $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}$.

Comment: ok and why you multiplied by (sin,cos), the law doesn't say so

Comment: Do you know what a Jacobian is? Why downvote an answer before you understand what it's saying?

Comment: Did you look at my points before claiming so? I only have 31 so I can't downvote!

Comment: Sorry for assuming. To a differentiable function $f(x_1, \ldots, x_m) = (f_1(x_1, \ldots, x_m) , \ldots, f_n(x_1, \ldots, x_m))$ we may associate a matrix $Df$ defined by $Df_{ij} = \frac{\partial f_i}{\partial x_j}$. The chain rule says $D(f \circ g) = Df \cdot Dg$ where $\cdot$ denotes matrix multiplication. In components, this means $\frac{\partial (f \circ g)_i}{\partial x_j} = \sum_k \frac{\partial f_i}{\partial x_k} \frac{\partial g_k}{\partial x_j}$.

Comment: So you can delete them